# SOLR how to define the data import handler for fields having several possible values per field?

Tags: database, indexing, solr, multivalue

I would like to **create an index** from my database data.
Currently I use a SQL view for extract the data from the base.
In my results I have an unique ID per result and **each result can contains several possible another ids** for one of the column that I need to search.

For example from one store I have 3 columns : **ID, NAME, PRODUCTS_ID**. PRODUCTS_ID has possibly several values per store. How I can index into SOLR such document. Must I create one document per products_id (and after that I need to make in someway distinct of the results) or I can use another way to present this results ? I saw that there is **multiValued** configuration, but is there a best way to done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the schema.xml your filed must be mulitvalued. Example

```
<field name="specialDeliveryTimes" type="int" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

2) In the SQL statement to must join the values with , Example using Oracle:

```
LISTAGG(AOP_LOCATIONID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AOP_LOCATIONID) AS SPECIALDELIVERYTIMES
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this solution the next week.

Comment: We are using this solution for our e-commerce shop. Works great.

Comment: Thank you for the example. It works for me, juste I needed to add some extra code. I will put it here down.

Answer (score 0):

Here the implementation of the solution proposed By Simas_ch.

In **db-data-config.xml** define:

```
<dataConfig>
   <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="***" 
      url="jdbc:****" 
      user="***" password="***"/>
   <document>
    <entity name="operation" transformer="RegexTransformer"
        pk="ID"
        query="SELECT * FROM GRC.V_SOLR_REGISTRAR_FR_CATALOG@GRCLINK" 
    >
       <field column="fieldDB" splitBy="," sourceColName="fieldSolr"/>
```

It is important to put **transformer="RegexTransformer"** and **splitBy="," sourceColName="TOP_SERVICE_ID"**.

After in **schema.xml** define as describe previosly the field :

```
<field name="fieldSolr" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Where **multiValued** is important.

And in the **SQL query** make a concatenation :

```
LISTAGG(test, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY test) AS fieldDB
```